# httpclient api unauthorized 401 error in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, httpclient

I'm trying to get some information from the following api url:

http://id-pension.pension.gov.iq/Gatway/PC_FetchIdentificationInfo/

using the following httpclient code:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Pensioner_Number)){
            var authString = "SWRpbnRpdGZjYXRpb25fR2F0V2F5Ol9aM2lpMkVK";// Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Idintitfcation_GatWay:_Z3ii2EJ"));
            HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
            handler.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + authString);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://id-pension.pension.gov.iq/Gatway/PC_FetchIdentificationInfo/" + Pensioner_Number);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
```

but always returns unauthorized 401 error.

I checked the authString several times but the error is keeping occurring.

Note that, I'm using asp.net core, the code above called when searching pensioner number ongetasync.

Comment: Does the authString valid when you try to request outside of code (i.e. from Postman, curl, etc.)?

Comment: The URL is not found. Make sure the URL is correct.

Comment: @stuck yes I checked it using Postman, and it works fine.

Comment: @jdweng yes it's correct. but the error is the same

Comment: The error using a browser said "URL NOT FOUND".  The webpage doesn't exist.  Try with your browser.

Comment: @jdweng The url should be followed by query {pensior number}

Comment: Note that, API url is closed after 2 pm

Comment: How are you passing the reuqest using postmain could you please include that sample here?

Comment: Thanks for the tip on HttpClientHandler and UseDefaultCredentials = true.

Answer (score 0):

You usually need to convert your authString this way:

byte[] authenticationByte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(authString);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(authenticationByte));

then if it doesn't work you can verify in the api documention if you might need other things in your header.

(I am sorry for the scuffed answer with the code as a string, StackOverflow is not cooperating with me right now)